# How to add a numeric order to the GridView using RowDataBound?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I am trying to change the value of the first cell in each row in the GridVie by giving it a number starting from 1. It means that I want to add order to the list of things that will be displayed in the GridView.

I am using GridView RowDataBound method but now I don't know to set the limit of the for loop in it. Could anyone help me with this?

My code-behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) { 
            for(int i=1, i<; i++)
                e.Row.Cells[0].Text = i;
        }
    }
```

Comment: try to get the gridview row count and check i < gridview.rows.count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requirement is "change the value of the first cell in each row", it would be more like:

```
private int _rowIndex=0;
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) { 
                e.Row.Cells[0].Text = _rowIndex.ToString();
               _rowIndex++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it will return of cell count:

```
int cells = ((TableRow) (e.Row)).Cells.Count;
```